# Correctly setup firebase database rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following rules for my database. My database structure is as follows in the database

[image]

My rules for my database are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I do a query to read the books under a user or add a new book under a user, will this rule still apply and only allow users who have a correct user id to add the book? Or will I need to drill down to Books and add that rule? Something like...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission cascades downwards in the database. So once a user has read or write permission on `/Users/$uid` they also have that same permission on the `Books` node under there.

For more on this, see the documentation on [read and write permissions cascase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade).